# At what age did Kakashi invent the chidori

Tags: naruto

Is there any record of how old Kakashi actually was when he invented the Chidori? I know it was before Kakashi Gaiden when Obito died, so he must have been less than 10 right?

Answer (score 3):

You are correct to say that Kakashi invented Chidori prior to Obito's death, but his age is never officially stated. However, there are some details from the *Boruto* series (take with a grain of salt) where we can deduce that Kakashi would have been roughly 11 or 12 years old.

> Minato was needed on the front lines at the time, leaving Kakashi, **recently promoted to jōnin at age 12<sup>[Boruto episode 36]</sup>** in charge. [...] Shortly after entering Kusa, they encountered an Iwa-scout, Mahiru. Kakashi tried to eliminate him with his **new jutsu, Chidori**, but the attack speed left him vulnerable to counter-attack
>
> [Source](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Kakashi_Hatake)